# Construct a LPCWSTR on WinCE in C++ (Zune/ZDK)

Tags: c++, string, windows-ce, zune

What's a good way to construct an LPCWSTR on WinCE 6?  I'd like to find something similar to String.Format() in C#.  My attempt is:

```
OSVERSIONINFO   vi;

memset (&vi, 0, sizeof vi);
vi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof vi;
GetVersionEx (&vi);

char buffer[50];
int n = sprintf(buffer, "The OS version is: %d.%d", vi.dwMajorVersion, vi.dwMinorVersion);

ZDKSystem_ShowMessageBox(buffer, MESSAGEBOX_TYPE_OK);
```

That ZDKSystem_ShowMessageBox refers to the ZDK for hacked Zunes available at:
http://zunedevwiki.org

This line of code works well with the message box call:

```
ZDKSystem_ShowMessageBox(L"Hello Zune", MESSAGEBOX_TYPE_OK);
```

My basic goal is to look at the exact version of WinCE running on a Zune HD to see which features are available (i.e. is it R2 or earlier?).

Also I haven't seen any tags for the ZDK so please edit if something is more fitting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sprintf is for narrow strings. `LPCWSTR` is a `const WCHAR *`, so you need wide characters, and the right function.

E.g.

```
WCHAR buf[100];
StringCchPrintfW(buf, _countof(buf), L"Hello, world!");
```

or using generic text functions, and compiling with UNICODE,

```
TCHAR buf[100];
StringCchPrintf(buf, _countof(buf), _T("Hello, world!"));
```

(There are other functions you could use, such as `_stprintf_s`, `swprintf_s`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
CString buffer;
buffer.Format(_T("The OS version is: %d.%d"), vi.dwMajorVersion, vi.dwMinorVersion);
```